# Rhythmbox 2.98 crashes all the time

Tags: rhythmbox

The default version of rhythmbox is 2.98 and it always crashes after a long period of pause of playing. How can i upgrade this version to a newer one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before doing complex stuff, try just disabling "Watch my library" and crossfade in preferences. These are the most complex tasks Rhythmbox can do.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest downloading the latest version (2.99.1) from http://ftp.acc.umu.se/pub/GNOME/sources/rhythmbox/2.99/rhythmbox-2.99.1.tar.xz
this needs installing with the following commands:

First change to the place where you downloaded the file to:

```
cd Downloads
```

Next you need to extract the file with

```
sudo apt-get install unp
unp rhythmbox-2.99.1.tar.xz
```

This will install unp which will be used for extracting files from the archive while preserving the directory hierarchical structure. Then unpacking the file.

Then we need to install it.

Firstly we enter the newly created folder

```
cd rhythmbox-2.99.1
```

Now to configure the file we enter:

```
./configure
```

Next We make the file:

```
make
```

Finally we install it

```
make install
```

You may then need to reboot, but that should be it.

## Edit

The long winded way would be:

Run the following in Terminal

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

to update the system. Then:

```
sudo apt-get install <dependency>
```

Then try again. This will install the missing packages first.

Comment: When making the ./configure gives this error: checking for gobject-introspection... configure: error: gobject-introspection-1.0 is not installed
. I run this: apt-get install gobject-introspection, but keeps giving the same error. Can you help me? Thank you

Comment: using the dpkg -l appears: gobject-introspection                1.36.0-1                i386

Comment: run the following command in Terminal `sudo apt-get install -f` with no package name, this should cure this as it will install all required packages

Comment: it did not. The error remains.

Comment: OK, I have added a bit more to the answer, replace `<package>` with `gobject-introspection-1.0`

Comment: apt-get install gobject-introspection-1.0 still gives error. Note that it installed the 1.36.0-1

Comment: sudo apt-get update - ok
sudo apt-get upgrade - ok 
sudo apt-get install gobject-introspection-1.0 ->error

Comment: how about `sudo apt-get install 'gobject-introspection*'` or `sudo apt-get install gobject-introspection`? after that, I think I'm out of ideas

Comment: it says that apt-get install 'gobject-introspection*' is already installed with the last version.

Answer (score 0):

### A word of warning: this method ruined my Rhythmbox installation. I can't run 2.99 and have unresolvable dependency issues when trying to install 2.98.

---

Though Barafu Albino has given the answer that solved your problem I would still like to provide the answer to the question of how to update Rhythmbox to a newer one if anyone is interested in that.

You can update Rhythmbox to 2.99.1 through a PPA. Open up Terminal and type in the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:dobey/rhythmbox-dailies
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rhythmbox
```

The PPA indicates it's daily builds of Rhythmbox though that doesn't seem to be the case. Rhythmbox 3.0 was released recently. I don't know if this PPA will automatically update to that version.

Source: [LinuxG.net](http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-rhythmbox-2-99-on-ubuntu-13-10-13-04-and-linux-mint-16-15/)

Comment: I just tried this and while the update works and Rhythmbox install, it doesn't work for me (13.04). I'm leaving the answer here in case it's useful to anyone but I'm reverting back to 2.98. I'm actually have difficulties with that cause I have dependency issues now. Proceed with caution!