# I cant configure rhythmbox as gobject-introspection 1 is not installed

Tags: installation, rhythmbox, gobject

Previously I advised someone on how to upgrade to Rhythmbox to version 2.99.1 [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/312840/rhythmbox-2-98-crashes-all-the-time/312846#312846). However they couldn't upgrade due to gobject-introspection-1.0 not being installed. I couldn't help them.

Now, with a brand new computer, I am getting the same problem as they had. here is the result ov `./configure`

```
simon@simon-TS44HR:~/Downloads/rhythmbox-2.99.1$ ./configure
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for gobject-introspection... configure: error: gobject-introspection-1.0 is not installed
```

I tried to install gobject-introspection with the following

```
simon@simon-TS44HR:~/Downloads/rhythmbox-2.99.1$ sudo apt-get -f install gobject-introspection
[sudo] password for simon: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
gobject-introspection is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

so I tried :

```
simon@simon-TS44HR:~/Downloads/rhythmbox-2.99.1$ sudo apt-get -f install gobject-introspection-1.0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package gobject-introspection-1.0
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'gobject-introspection-1.0'
```

I have not really got to grips with installing software properly, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, you can do `sudo apt-get install libgirepository1.0-dev`. But then you get an `intltool` error, so you do `sudo apt-get install intltool`. But then you get another error =D.

Comment: I had tried so many ways, but, after following your answer below, I finally got it to work. Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: Man, how did you missed that the headers end in `-dev`? :/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to install the `gobject-introspection` development package (library) in order for `./configure` (or `pkg-config`) to see it. This package is [libgirepository1.0-dev [image: Install libgirepository1.0-dev]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/libgirepository1.0-dev). However, on my machine, ever after installing this package, I kept encountering errors on other missing dependencies for the compiling to work.

The easiest way to satisfy all the requirements for compiling Rhythmbox is to execute the command:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep rhythmbox
```

This will install a bunch of libraries and packages that are needed for compiling Rhythmbox (it will need to get around 76 MB at the time of this answer).

Once it's done, do `./configure` again and it should not spit out any errors. Continue with `sudo make` and `sudo make install`.

After installing, `rhythmbox` might not run, and running it from the terminal will give you:

```
rhythmbox: error while loading shared libraries: librhythmbox-core.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

To fix this, do:

```
sudo cp /usr/local/lib/librhythmbox-core.so.7 /usr/lib
```

**Source: [[Rhythmbox-devel] Problem with 2.99.1 installation](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/rhythmbox-devel/2013-June/msg00018.html)**.

I just tried all of this, and [it worked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alNT1.png).

Comment: I started getting excited, but on `sudo make` I get `make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'all'. Stop.` in `Downloads/rhythmbox-2.99.1/macros` any clues what could cause this, or should I start again?

Comment: I sorted it out, First I deleted the extracted files and unpacked them again, next I followed your instructions and everything ran smoothly. I am syncing my iPhone as I type :) Thank you so much.

Comment: @SimplySimon I also have not been able to sync my iphone 4 (iOS 6.1.3) on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and Rhythmbox version 2.96. If I update to the newest version of Rhythmbox following the steps above will I be able to sync my iphone with the firmware that I have? Thanks

Comment: @user87317 I have an iPhone 5 (iOS 6.14) on Ubuntu 13.04 Desktop. Rhtythmbox version 2.99.1, and everything is working well.

Comment: @SimplySimon I followed the steps above provided by Alaa but I get an error indicating that I need gtk+ >=3.6.0 but my version is 3.4.2. I did a search online but I could not find a way to update GTK without upgrading from Ubuntu 12.04. Is there a way?

Comment: I just had a quick search, but the answer seems always to be to update the OS to 13.04 :(

Comment: I found gtk 3.6.1 for 12.04 available in [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ricotz/+archive/testing). Add it by `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ricotz/testing`.