# Iphone 4 and ubuntu 13.04

Tags: iphone

Hello I have a big problem,

When I am trying to sync my music with iPhone 4 using rhythmbox it just exits.

When I am trying to sync my music using banshee its just freezes.

anyone have ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is fixed with the latest version of rythmbox 2.99.1

You can download the latest version from http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/rhythmbox/2.99/

Comment: I have another problem, cant install rhythmbox 2.99 configure: error: gobject-introspection-1.0 is not installed 

whats the problem?

Comment: I'm having the same problem, trying to sort it now.

Comment: Well, I have just put up a 100 point bounty for a fix to this as my iPhone is not working with rythmbox either. I'll let you know if I get a response - keep watching http://askubuntu.com/questions/319568/i-cant-configure-rhythmbox-as-gobject-introspection-1-is-not-installed