# Downgrading Rhythmbox 2.99 to 2.97 without losing Playlists

Tags: 12.10, rhythmbox

I installed Rhythmbox 2.99 on Ubuntu 12.10 following the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/312840/rhythmbox-2-98-crashes-all-the-time/312846#312846) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/319568/i-cant-configure-rhythmbox-as-gobject-introspection-1-is-not-installed/330308#comment429721_330308).

This version of Rhythmbox seems to be a little buggy and I would like to downgrade to 2.97, but I want to do this without losing my personal settings (playlists). How can I do this?

I should also point out that when I open the Ubuntu Software Center and I search Rhythmbox, it shows as installed (green checkmark), but the version in the Ubuntu Software Center is 2.97. I'm not sure if this means that I have both versions installed. When I open Rhythmbox, it opens 2.99 and that's the only version that appears when I search in the dash.

I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The version you have manually compiled and installed as actually been installed into a system local folder - `/usr/local/lib/rhythmbox` - thus any binaries (executables) take precedence over your current v2.97 install which is in `/usr/lib/rhythmbox`

To uninstall your system-local version, you need to run the uninstall routine from the folder you initially extracted, compiled and installed in.

For example, lets say you extracted v2.99 in `~/Downloads/rhythmbox-2.99`

```
cd ~/Downloads/rhythmbox-2.99
sudo make uninstall
```

This will remove all traces of the local version, leaving you with the default system version of rhythmbox that is still installed.

It is safe to do this, since your local playlists are stored in your home folder in the folder `~/.local/share/rhythmbox`.  This is not touched when installing the newer version of rhythmbox.